# How I can create build file with Node.JS script?

Tags: node.js

How I can do it with Node.js(**script file not in cmd consol**):

1. go to the folder with the project
2. do *npm i*
3. do *webpack -p*
   ?

Comment: `cd /your_project && npm i && webpack -p` . Just put it into a bash or sh file

Comment: not cmd panel. it need me in a script file.

Comment: maybe I need use this function child_process.exec ?

Comment: you want to start this from node.js?

Comment: yes. For exapmle: I have a build.js file with this script. After that I start command in cmd  - node build.js - in the finals, I get ready to bundle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a bash script with all you want to do:

**yourbash.sh:**

```
cd /yourdirectory
npm i
webpack -p
```

then just spawn this process in your node

```
const spawn = require('child_process').exec

spawn('sh yourbash.sh', [], function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) { console.log(err) } // handle error

    // standard output from the bash script
    console.log(stdout)
})
```

Alternatively, you can skip the bash file entirely by doing this:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').exec

spawn('cd /yourdirectory && npm i && webpack -p', [], function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) { console.log(err) } // handle error

    // standard output from the bash script
    console.log(stdout)
})
```

Comment: can i do it with out  bash script? only node script

Comment: Oh, added this to my answer. You can use && to wait for the previous command to finish before running the next task. So you can just spawn `cd /yourdirectory && npm i && webpack -p`. Tested it and works fine.

Comment: try to execute the `cd /yourdirectory && npm i && webpack -p` from shell directly to figure out if the command by itself works.